# How do I append awk script to a file?

Tags: awk, scripting

hello i have the following awk script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f 

{for(i=4;i<=7;i++) j+=$i;  print "Student",NR",",$1,$2",",j/4; j=0}
```

and i want to append the output to a new file (newfile.txt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Where mention output file inside `awk` code itself.

```
{for(i=4;i<=7;i++) j+=$i;  print "Student" OFS NR",",$1,$2"," OFS j/4 >> (output_file); j=0}
```

---

---

OR 2nd way is when you are running your `awk` code where `script` is the script name you are calling to run your awk program eg-->

```
./script >> output_file
```

---

---

In case you want to run an `awk` one-liner to get output into a output file then try following.

```
awk -v output_file="Output.txt" '{for(i=4;i<=7;i++) j+=$i;  print "Student" OFS NR",",$1,$2"," OFS j/4 >> (output_file); j=0}' Input_file
```

In above code I have created a variable named `output_file` whose value you could keep it as per your wish too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a shebang to call awk from a shell script as it robs you of the ability to separate your functionality by what each (the shell or awk) does best. Make your shell script look like this instead (using whichever shell you use for the shebang):

```
#!/bin/env bash

awk '
{for(i=4;i<=7;i++) j+=$i;  print "Student",NR",",$1,$2",",j/4; j=0}
' "$@" >> newfile.txt
```